# Multihilo, ¿Mejor forma de tratar el método `run()`?

Tags: java

Buenas, me gustaría saber cómo harían ustedes para tratar el método `run()`en un servidor TCP. El servidor es este:

```
public class Servidor{
    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception{
        ServerSocket serv;
        SesionTCP session[] = new SesionTCP[100];

        int i=0;
        serv = new ServerSocket(8080);

        while(true){
            Socket s;
            s = serv.accept();
            session[i]=new SesionTCP(s);
            session[i].start();
            System.out.println("Nueva conexion entrante: "+serv);
            i++;
            if(i==100){
                i=0;
            }
            serv.close();
        }
    }
}
```

Cómo se puede observar, instancio la sesión TCP dentro del servidor, para luego iniciarla mediante el método `.start()`.

Bien, el caso es que debo crear la `class SesionTCP`, la cual debe hacer una serie de cosas:

```
class SesionTCP extends Thread {
    Socket s;
    PrintWriter out;
    BufferedReader in;
    SesionTCP(Socket s) {
        this.s=s;
    } // fin constructor
    public void run(){
        try{
            in = new BufferedReader (new InputStreamReader(s.getInputStream()));
            out = new PrintWriter (new OutputStreamWriter(s.getOutputStream()));
        }catch(IOException e){ return; } // fin try-catch

        out.println("Mensaje del servidor");

        //LLamada a los diferentes métodos para tratar los mensajes
        int res;
        res=SesionTCP.helloserver();

        out.close();
        in.close();
        s.close();
    } // fin run
        public int helloserver(){
            String ip;
            String entrada;
            try{
                entrada=in.readLine();
                System.out.println(entrada+"he entrado en el hello");
                //Obtenemos la IP del cliente que invoca al servidor
                ip = s.getRemoteSocketAddress().toString();
            }catch(IOException e){
                System.out.println(e);
                return 0;
            }
            if (entrada.equals("HELLO "+ip)){
                return 1;
            }else{
                return 0;
            }
        }
    } // fin clase SesionTCP
```

Me explico, mi dilema consiste en que quiero tratar los mensajes que recibo del cliente cómo comandos, y según el comando que recibo hacer una cosa u otra. Por ejemplo, si el cliente escribe el comando de inicio "HELLO xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx" con su ip, el método `run()` debe llamar al método `hello` para tratar dicho mensaje.

Cuanto intento llamar al método `helloserver()` me da el error de "non-static method helloserver() cannot be referenced from static context".

¿Cual sería la mejor forma de implementarlo? ¿Se puede hacer sin llamar a métodos, metiendo todo en el `run()`? ¿O quedaría muy sucio?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

La llamada al método la estás haciendo efectivamente desde un contexto estático, pero es error al llamarlo no tiene nada que ver con usar hilos ni el método `run()`.

Cambia la línea:

```
res=SesionTCP.helloserver();
```

Por esta otra:

```
res = this.helloserver();
```

Por otra parte, y al margen de tu preguna, veo que al final de cada `run()` cierras el `Socket`. Fíjate que estás usando un único socket para todos las sesiones que instancias. Preveo que el primer hilo que llegue a la línea `s.close()` (que no tiene por qué ser el primero que arranques) cerrará el socket y el resto se lo va a encontrar cerrado y te dará error en tiempo de ejecución.

Comment: Efectivamente, el error estaba ahí, a la hora del llamarlo. Antes de leer tu comentario probé con `res= helloserver();` simplemente, y también compiló, e incluso probé y si se metía al método. ¿Esta mal esta forma de hacerlo?

Comment: No, es lo mismo, pero con `this` te aseguras que apuntas al entorno de `este` objeto. Es lo mismo que haces con `this.s = s` donde tienes que diferencias de qué `s` estás hablando (atributo del objeto o parámetro)

Comment: Vale, pues muchísimas gracias de verdad, llevo cómo 3 días leyendo foros en inglés. hasta que vi que StackOverflow estaba también en español, y probé suerte aquí. El problema fue que de un error tonto, cómo es el llamar al método de esa manera, fue derivando en que pensaba que mi error estaba en otro lado, y no ahí, y al final ya no sabía ni qué estaba haciendo. Ahora he probado el primer comando y ya me lo hace perfectamente, seguiré programando, muchas gracias!!